# How to find the last row of a table and clear certain columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table (`Table1`) that will grow by adding rows to the end. I need a code to find the last row of that table and clear the values/formulas for columns D,E,H,K,L,M.

I am using the following code but it clears all contents from row 2 to the last row instead of just the last row.

```
Sub ClearRowData()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("D2:D" & Lastrow).Clear

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("D" & Lastrow).Clear`

Comment: ^ Similar logic for the other columns.

Comment: Would I have to repeat the same code but change it for the other columns? Or can I repeat the `Range` line of code within what I have posted?

Comment: It may be easier / more logical to work directly with the `ListObject` model instead. It's pretty clear with intellisense and all about finding the rows and the columns by name/index.

Comment: Can anyone advise if the same code can be used to find the last table row then add a formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic thing that will clear the lastrow for each, so long as it's the same for each column. I'm not sure what the purpose of your `with` statement was, but I removed that as well.

There's fancier ways to achieve what you're doing, but it's simple enough to do it this way.

```
Sub ClearRowData()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 
Range("D" & Lastrow).Clear
Range("E" & Lastrow).Clear
Range("H" & Lastrow).Clear
Range("K" & Lastrow).Clear
Range("L" & Lastrow).Clear
Range("M" & Lastrow).Clear

End Sub
```